# MySQL: host for root user changed

Tags: mysql, root, host

There was a user `root@localhost` and I made it `root@127.0.0.1` via `mysql -u root -p` command:

```
`UPDATE mysql.user SET host=127.0.0.1 WHERE user=root;`
```

Now, I cannot get back to `mysql -u root -p`, even if I do it this way: `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p`:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

Guys, what is the best way to put things back?

Comment: These commands don't change anything. Describe **exactly** what you've done.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Done, added some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**
Stop the server and start it again with the `--skip-grant-tables` option. Undo your changes, stop the server again and start it without before mentioned option.

---

Stop mysqld and restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges. Because this is insecure, you might want to use --skip-grant-tables in conjunction with --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting.

Connect to the mysqld server with this command:

```
shell> mysql
```

Issue the following statements in the mysql client. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET host = 'localhost'
    ->                   WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change.